# Hibernate many to many fetching associated objects

Tags: java, hibernate

```html
@Entity
@Table(name = "MATCHES")
public class Match implements Serializable{
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 @Column(name = "MATCH_ID")
 private Long id;

 @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "matches", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 private Set<Team> teams = new HashSet<Team>();
}
```

```html
@Entity
@Table(name = "Teams")
public class Team implements Serializable {
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 @Column(name = "TEAM_ID")
 private long id;

 @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 @JoinTable(name = "TEAM_MATCH", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "TEAM_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
   @JoinColumn(name = "MATCH_ID") })
 private Set<Match> matches = new HashSet<Match>();
}
```

I got those classes, now I want to get all the matches and let's say, print names of both teams.

```html
public List getAllMatches() {
  Session session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
  Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();
  Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Match.class, "match");
  criteria.createAlias("match.teams", "mt", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN);
  List result = criteria.list();
  t.commit();
  session.close();
  return result;
 }
```

But when I invoke that method, result has size 2 when I got only 1 match in my table. Both of those matches in result have 2 teams, which is correct. I have no idea why this happends. What I want is to have one Match object with two Team objects in 'teams' set, but I have two of those Match objects. They are fine, but there are two of them. I'm completely new to this and have no idea how to fix those criterias. I tried deleting 'FetchType.LAZY' from @ManyToMany in Team but it doesn't work. Team also has properties like Players/Trainer etc. which are in their own tables, but I don't want to dig that deep yet, baby steps. I wonder tho if doing such queries is a good idea, should I just return Matches and then if I want to get Teams, get them in another session?

Edit: I added `criteria.setResultTransformer(DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer.INSTANCE);` and it works, is that how I was suppose to fix that or this is for something completely different and I just got lucky?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the duplication is a result of your `createAlias` call, which besides having this side effect is redundant in the first place.

By calling `createAlias` with those arguments, you are telling Hibernate to not just return all matches, but to first cross index the MATCHES table with the TEAM_MATCH table and return a result for each matching pair of rows. You get one result for a row in the matches table paired with the many-to-many mapping to the first team, and another result for the same row in the matches table paired with the many-to-many mapping to the second team.

I'm guessing your intent with that line was to tell Hibernate to fetch the association. This is not necessary, Hibernate will fetch associated objects on its own automatically when needed.

Simply delete the `criteria.createAlias` call, and you should get the result you expected - with one caveat. Because the association is using lazy fetching, Hibernate won't load it until you access it, and if that comes after the session is closed you will get a `LazyInitializationException`. In general I would suggest you prefer solving this by having the session opened and closed at a higher level of abstraction - getting all matches is presumably part of some larger task, and in most cases you should really use one session for the duration of the entire task unless there are substantial delays (such as waiting for user input) involved. Changing that would likely require significant redesign of your code, however; the quick solution is to simply loop over the result list and call `Hibernate.initialize()` on the `teams` collection in each `Match`. Or you could just change the fetch type to eager, if the performance cost of always loading the association whether or not you need it is acceptable.

Comment: I would have to do getAllMatches() and then get the Teams in the same session, but I'm opening a new session in getAllMatches(), should I start the session before getAllMatches() and then use factory.getCurrentSession() inside it?

Comment: @Shadov That is what I suggest as the preferred solution, yes. Just make sure to still close the session when you're done (with the whole task), and keep in mind you will need to make sure there's an active session anywhere that calls `getAllMatches()`.

Comment: Ok, I will try with parameters or something, just read about `getCurrentSession()` and it would require one session per app and I don't want that. Thank you very much for help.